# Distinct one value from multiple same records result query

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, stored-procedures

I have this result on stored procedure in sql server (result of multiples left join):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/be597/1

I need to send on each email the content of columns article, code.

I thought about the function GROUP_CONCAT but I do not think that this is the good solution because it formats me the text in the query.

`SELECT mail, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('Article: ', article, ' - Code: ', code), '\n') FROM mail GROUP BY mail`

I would like to keep the data in the stored procedure for later use.

How can I do it in sql ?

I imagine that this should be a recurring problem with SQL queries but I am a beginner so I allow myself to ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` is a Mysql feature, SQL Server doesn't support this kind of function. And you could use to keep format by `FOR XML PATH`

```
SELECT
    mail,
    STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + article
    FROM mail
    WHERE (mail = mainMail.mail)
    FOR XML PATH (''))
    ,1,2,'') AS Articles,
    STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + CAST(code AS VARCHAR(5))
    FROM mail
    WHERE (mail = mainMail.mail)
    FOR XML PATH (''))
    ,1,2,'') AS Codes
FROM mail mainMail
GROUP BY mail
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/be597/4)

> I would like to keep the data in the stored procedure for later use.

You don't keep the data in the stored procedure. You keep the query in the stored procedure and execute.

Comment: Yes, my bad, i have used GROUP_CONCAT on my tests in MySQL. This query return results like GROUP_CONCAT. Is it possible to get article and code on separate columns instead comma ? I need to keep formated data for later use.